# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x6c88000)

Tags: xcode, crash, cocoapods

My app crashes on iOS 14.5, but works fine on iOS 15+

Does anyone have an idea how to solve it?

Error log:

```
`grpc_core::promise_detail::FreestandingActivity::Handle::DropActivity() (.cold.1):
    0x109d9b367 <+0>:  pushq  %rbp
    0x109d9b368 <+1>:  movq   %rsp, %rbp
    0x109d9b36b <+4>:  leaq   0xa15bd3(%rip), %rdi      ; "/var/folders/hz/7v68p4h95sb2ypb614xp20jc00r7sc/T/ZipRelease/2023-04-27T16-15-03/project-ios/Pods/gRPC-Core/src/core/lib/promise/activity.cc"
    0x109d9b372 <+11>: leaq   0xa1934d(%rip), %rcx      ; "assertion failed: %s"
    0x109d9b379 <+18>: leaq   0xa15c51(%rip), %r8       ; "activity_ != nullptr"
    0x109d9b380 <+25>: pushq  $0x2f
    0x109d9b382 <+27>: popq   %rsi
    0x109d9b383 <+28>: pushq  $0x2
    0x109d9b385 <+30>: popq   %rdx
    0x109d9b386 <+31>: xorl   %eax, %eax
    0x109d9b388 <+33>: callq  0x109e94670               ; gpr_log
    0x109d9b38d <+38>: callq  0x10a0b9a86               ; symbol stub for: abort
    0x109d9b392 <+43>: pushq  %rbp
    0x109d9b393 <+44>: movq   %rsp, %rbp
    0x109d9b396 <+47>: movq   0xcc4413(%rip), %rax      ; (void *)0x0000000006c88000
->  0x109d9b39d <+54>: cmpb   $0x0, (%rax)
    0x109d9b3a0 <+57>: jne    0x109d9b3ba               ; <+83>
    0x109d9b3a2 <+59>: leaq   0xe27dc7(%rip), %rcx      ; vtable for grpc_core::activity_detail::Unwakeable
    0x109d9b3a9 <+66>: addq   $0x10, %rcx
    0x109d9b3ad <+70>: movq   0xcc449c(%rip), %rdx      ; (void *)0x0000000006c88000
    0x109d9b3b4 <+77>: movq   %rcx, (%rdx)
    0x109d9b3b7 <+80>: movb   $0x1, (%rax)
    0x109d9b3ba <+83>: popq   %rbp
    0x109d9b3bb <+84>: retq   
    0x109d9b3bc <+85>: addb   %al, (%rax)
    0x109d9b3be <+87>: addb   %al, (%rax)
```